# Strange MySQL duplicate record when updating row by mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I encountered strange behavior when updating a table through mysqli (php). I have a simple table with records:

```
    mysql> describe reports_1;
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
    | line_number | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
    | username    | varchar(30)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    | id          | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    | stamp       | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
    | content     | varchar(1000)    | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
    +-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

line_number is the primary key (and id is a foreign key). When I update this table in the CLI, all is fine:

```
    mysql> update reports_1 set content='works fine' where line_number='24';
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I execute *exactly* the same query from within php, viz.

```
    $q = "update reports_1 set content='works fine' where line_number='24'";
    $update = $connection->query($q);
```

I get a double (!) update in my table:

```
    mysql> select * from reports_1;
    +-------------+----------+------+---------------------+------------+
    | line_number | username | id   | stamp               | content    |
    ...
    |          24 | user     |  210 | 2016-02-04 11:56:14 | works fine |
    |          25 | user     |    0 | 2016-02-04 11:56:14 | works fine |
    +-------------+----------+------+---------------------+------------+
```

As one can see, very unexpectedly (for me) the update gets copied, given a new key of its own, the time stamp is the same, and the foreign key is set to zero.

I cannot wrap my head around what causes this! Is there anybody who could shed some light on this behavior? Is it expected? Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

**Edit upon request**
The php script receives data sent from a js function that took the value of a textarea field:

```
    if (isset($_POST['line_number']))
    {
        $line_nr = $_POST['line_number'];
        $update = $_POST['record'];
        $q15 = "update reports_1 set content='$update' where line_number=$line_nr";
        $edit = $connection2->query($q15);
        if (!$edit) die ("Database access failed: " . $connection2->error);
    }
```

That's really all there is to it...

Comment: try removing single quotation marks .Use 24 instead of '24'. Just a guess, because of their type(integer and string)

Comment: how line_number is primary and exists twice?

Comment: No line_number is not twice. It's 24 and 25 @GoudaElalfy.

Comment: Hi Gaurav Rai, thanks for you suggestion, it didn't solve the problem though... Although I now think it should be hidden in my sanitization: If I include a < in contents, it ends up in both records: first as < and second as &gt;. I use stripslashes, striptags, htmlentities and then real_escape_string. But apparently I'm overdoing something there... It doesn't happen with a normal insert though...

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table? Are you certain that there is no way code can be executed to do an insert as well?

Comment: Hi Kickstart, thanks for your suggestion. No, it is a really basic table and basic code (level of what you'd find in a typical introductory chapter...)

Comment: Very strange. An update shouldn't do an insert. How big is the php script and can you post it above?

Comment: I made the edit kickstart

Comment: What you need sir are [**unit tests**](https://phpunit.de/). I doubt this is the code that's causing the issue. An `UPDATE` query won't add records.. period. So unless there is a trigger involved , the above code is not causing the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that the insert isn't done after on your php code? Can you put an exit(0) on the final of the if, only to be sure that nobody happens after? Also did you already tried to use that query `$q15 = "update reports_1 set content='works fine' where line_number='24'";` that you mentioned? Or you only tested it with that variable injection?

Comment: Without a trigger the only way I can see this would do an insert is with SQL injection if your query method does a mysqli_multi_query. I would agree with @anolsi - use exit to terminate the script and see what has been updated / inserted (although if there is an insert before the update it won't identify the issue).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try to take an even more detailed look at this based on your suggestions...

Comment: Yeah @Kickstart. If the insert was done before we won't be able to see that. This is way I also asked if he already ran the query without any variable. On that case, it will do an insert with the values from the $_POST, and an update that is related with that line that we are analyzing.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for all the helpful comments! I am a bit strapped for time, and I want to take a serious look at it based on your suggestions. I will let you know, just wanted to show my appreciation for the many tips.